# How to generate word document having HTML as input from Novacode Docx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, docx

I need to generate word and pdf file from html data as input. For e.g if my html contains b tag then everything under the b tag should be generate bold.
I am using **iTextSharp** to generate the pdf file and **novacode docx** to generate word file and I have achieved this functionality in generating the pdf file with the below code:

```
iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(doc);
hw.Parse(new StringReader(model.HTMLContent));
```

But I am not able to generate the word file from html data. Any help would be great!

If Docx does not provide any solution for this requirement then I want to know what are the other options available for this functionality.
I want to know specially with these options do I need to have ms-office install on server or not? Or what type of doc file will these options generate I mean with doc extension or docx extension?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do something like this with word about a year ago, and I had no success, apparently docx files don't support showing html in them. I'd recommend to insert images and tables and other in the word not the exact html.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question. Can you please reply me again with more details if you know something more about my problem?

Comment: I don't remember exactly what we did at the end, but we didn't do this approach with the word. I haven't used much Docx but simple inserting text but it's quite powerful in inserting everything, you don't need to install MS word, maybe generate some view like what you want to pass for a print, and then try make it by Docs for word, sorry I know seems like a pain in ass solution!